# SQL query not displaying results

Tags: sql, search

I'm writing an SQL query and this is what I have so far. However, it's not displaying results despite them being present within the database. I've looked things over and I'm just not seeing what could be wrong with it. By chance, does anybody see what may be going awry here?

```
SELECT customer_Name AS "Customer Name", 
       customer_Telephone AS "Customer Tel.", 
       rent_date AS "Date Out", 
       date_due AS "Date Due", 
       (bike_Number +' ' + bike_Model) AS "Bike No. and Model"
FROM rental_record
  JOIN Customer using (customer_ID)
  JOIN bike_Record using (bike_Number)
WHERE sysdate > date_Due 
  AND time_Actual = NULL
ORDER BY date_due DESC;
```

Comment: You can't compare `NULL` using `=` in SQL. You need `time_actual IS NULL` instead. Also `+` is not used to concatenate strings in SQL, you need to use `||` for that. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @AdrianLynch: then `bike_number + ' '` would throw an error.

Comment: Please do not edit a "final solution" into your question. Instead, post your solution as a separate answer.

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
  AND time_Actual = NULL
```

To this:

```
  AND time_Actual IS NULL
```